# Control State and View State vs. Databinding

Tags: asp.net

Suppose I have a custom control like a `Table` with a varying number of rows in it.  What would be the advantages of using databinding (like in a `GridView`) if I went that route?  What would be the advantages if I used the control state to keep track of the number of rows?

**Edit:** Example.

Each `TableRow` in the `Table` object represents an employee.  Each `TableCell` contains a `TextBox` input control.  The user can add another blank employee (row) with a button under the `Table`.  Information entered must be maintained through postbacks.

Using the states method, the number of rows can be saved into the control state.  Since control state is loaded before view state, the number can be restored before the view state is restored (providing objects to take the view state and post values).

Binding with a GridView?  I don't know much about how this works.  From what I've seen, you can XML-serialize the data and save it to the `Value` property of a `Hidden` control.

Comment: Could you add a concrete example of what you're describing (with code) to the question?  Right now, it seems like a bit of a broad or vague question.

Comment: @jadarnel27 Done, somewhat.  I haven't written the code yet; I was trying to figure out the best way to do so first.

Comment: There is not much difference between control state and view state besides the fact that view state can be disabled and control state cannot. Standard data-binding controls like Repeater and GridView use view state (not control state) to track the number of data-bound items.